# partitions lost drive letters in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-management

i have following problem with my HDD in my laptop, i have win 7

my partitions are gone hide and not visible in my computer, when i try to look them in disk management the partitions which are hidden have no drive letter assigned, when i try to assign the drive letter or even try to format a drive this error messages every time and restating my laptop didn't make any difference. i am going to attach the screen shot of error[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you have assigned some other Letter for your Operating system  Disk.

> Run **[Partition master](http://www.partition-tool.com/)**  as Admin and configure your Disks.

Or else

> You should format the Entire PC .

If you are formatting,then do create a backup.

> You may also delete the partition and check if that is working:

See here for more details :

http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/